# My 09 kia sportage screams when starting in extremely cold weather

Tags: cold-weather

Wondering if a block heater would help? It only does it when we have extremely cold weather, I worry something is going to get damaged. It's a balmy -21°c here atm.  Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you had the serpentine belt replaced?  It may just be the belt that is slipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block heater would ABSOLUTELY help. I would bet it's your serpentine belt which is slipping against the alternator as it's trying to recharge the battery right after startup. While a block heater isn't going to help the battery directly, what it'll do is make it a ton easier for the engine to turn over when it's that cold, which means you'll need less starting power from the battery. The great side effect of a block heater is it will give you a warm vehicle MUCH faster after start up :)

Comment: Thank you, I will have the serpentine belt checked and look into having a block heater installed. This is the first vehicle I've owned that doesn't have one.